# safari doesn't (dynamically) refresh $.html() content

Tags: javascript, jquery, safari, dhtml

I have the following piece of code

```
$('#charactersRemaining').html(123-countChars(this.value));
```

Works in all browsers except Safari.
Even in Safari, if I click the content in the div area ( of id=charactersRemaining), it refreshes, but it doesn't refresh automatically/dynamically

Any way to force Safari to refresh?

```
$().html('new content');
```

Update: 
 I have used the following 'hack' (for safari). But still interested to know if I have missed any technical detail

```
$('#x').html('new'); 
$('#x').hide(); 
$('#x').fadeIn(); // or you could use .show();
```

Comment: This is not clear; what do you mean by "automatically"?  Safari definitely does update the view when the DOM is changed like that.  How/where are you running that code?

Comment: As I mentioned, the content is not dynamically updated.
To give an example, just like the char remaining feature in an edit box, the countdown is dynamic, but in safari it remained static, but If I double-click on the text(of characters remaining), it would show the updated content

Comment: I assure you that I do lots of dynamic DOM updates on my site, and it works fine in Safari without any "hacks". Are you talking about iOS (iPhone) Safari here?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/Tfxfn/ that works fine for me in Safari 5/Windows.

Comment: Pointy, Thanks for your help (especially for reminding me to use jsfiddle). But, I still have to use the hack to make it work. May be it's the context/css around the code (or some other combination of things). 

Without the hack, I still have to double-click on the content to view the update (on safari)


Thanks again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I found the issue. I had an image nearby (may be floating/layering over the text). Thus Safari didn't redraw the underlying text (or some quirk).

Anyway moved the image around and it works in safari too

Answer (score 0):

i had the exact same problem, but what i found out is that my elements that were having this problem had in style position relative. if i change that it works just fine.